# Visa for newborn delivered in India of Tier2 ICT parents

Tags: dependent-visa

I am tier2 ICT long term visa, my wife holding tier 2 ICT dependent visa. we recently had baby delivered in India. I am confused on the visa process, can you please help me understand what would  be visa type and the process to apply visa for my newborn. Thanks a lot.